# Aligning bootstrap next and prev buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched over internet that we cannot put the `.carousel-left`,`.carousel-right` in `.carousel-inner`. Before putting them out of the `.carousel-inner` it worked fine but after taking them it became like this:
[image]

And before it was this:
[image]

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mySlider" class="carousel slide" style="width: 600px; height:340px;">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img alt="" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/examples/slide-01.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Video Caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/examples/slide-01.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Video Caption 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#mySlider" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#mySlider" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap so I don't need to mension the CSS in here :)

Please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you avoid using these classes?

Comment: `.carousel-left`,`.carousel-right`

Comment: @Itay actually I wrote wrong there is no such class. :P

Comment: Did you try `pull-right` and `pull-left`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36168/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-itay)